# How do I limit a @foreach loop in relation to stored database entries?

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css

I am creating a blog using Laravel/PHP/Tailwindcss. I designed the blog page to have 6 blog cards using tailwind. When using `@foreach $posts as $post` the result is duplicated 6 times. I only want the blog card to populate with how many articles are in the database not repeating itself. In my case 6 for now.

Hopefully, this image can help provide more context in what I am trying to explain.

https://ibb.co/PYMMf3Z

https://ibb.co/NLyFRCG (#2)

Index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Blog')

@section('content')

@foreach ($posts as $post)

<body class="text-cw-grey-700 ">
  <main class="container mx-auto max-w-6xl px-5">
    <article class="border-t border-cw-grey-100 flex justify-between py-10">
      <a href="#" class="w-1/2 mr-12">
        <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="border-sm">
      </a>
      <div class="w-1/2 mt-4">
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Link</a>
        <h1 class="mb-3"><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-3xl text-cw-gray-800 leading-tight hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h1>
        <p class="leading-relaxed">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <div class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 row-gap-6">
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're duplicating the body tag. Is this what you're looking for?

```
@extends('layout')
@section('title', 'Blog')

@section('content')

<body class="text-cw-grey-700 ">
  <main class="container mx-auto max-w-6xl px-5">
    <article class="border-t border-cw-grey-100 flex justify-between py-10">
      <a href="#" class="w-1/2 mr-12">
        <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="border-sm">
      </a>
      <div class="w-1/2 mt-4">
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Link</a>
        <h1 class="mb-3"><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-3xl text-cw-gray-800 leading-tight hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h1>
        <p class="leading-relaxed">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--- begin posts container -->
    <div class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 row-gap-6">

    <!-- iterate posts --->
@foreach ($posts as $post)
      <article>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/T-Sky.jpg" alt="" class="mb-2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-cw-blue-300 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline text-sm mb-1 block">Text here</a>
        <h2><a href="#"
            class="font-bold font-work-sans text-xl text-cw-gray-900 hover:text-cw-blue-600 hover:underline ">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ $post->excerpt }}</p>
      </article>
@endforeach

    </div>
   </main>
</body>
@endsection
```

Comment: Hi, this is almost it yes. I would like to start iterating from the very first blog card, then proceed to the other 6 cards as I post content. I have added a screenshot to the main post.  A separate issue, the images are the same for all cards, but that will not be the case once I'm blogging. So, how would you approach to having the images change in each post?

Comment: Using moustache: `<img src="path/to/images/{{ $image_name_here }}`">

Comment: Great. And if it was a link to an image would it be <img src="link path" {{ $image_link }}" ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'link to an image' ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean copying an image address rather then downloading it to my image folder. For example, https://unsplash.com/photos/yWwob8kwOCk

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Copy the whole image location (which in our case is https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497366754035-f200968a6e72?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80) then paste it within src tag :) `<img src="..image URL here">`

Comment: Hello, that's okay. By doing what you suggested it would then repeat that same image for each card. Instead, I was thinking to hold the link in the database (create a new column) and call it by ```{{ $post->thumbnailPath }}``` or something similar.